# Bigquery Regexp_Extract Question - Extracting Only the First Name (mid placement) from Full Name Field

Tags: sql, regex

I want to use the Regexp_Extract function to isolate the first name from this string.

```
Full Name
Scott, John Smith
Jackson, Adrian Lee
Park, Julie Ann
```

Desired Output

```
John
Adrian
Julie
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the first string after the comma.  That would be:

```
select regexp_extract(full_name, ', ([^ ]+)') as first_name
```

Comment: REGEXP_EXTRACT(full_name, r",\s([a-zA-Z]+)") as first_name <--- This one also worked for me.

Comment: @EugenePark . . . That is fine.  It looks like a space in your question so there did not seem to be a need to generalize.